# Can I add framing to build a room under my basement staircase?

Tags: drywall, studs

I have space under the basement staircase that I want to make a proper room with door. On one side I have a concrete block wall, so there is no issue there and I can put a door in the front. But on the other side I cannot put drywall because existing studs are not aligned and metal post supporting the beam is outside the stud.

So can I solve this by adding additional studs on either side to the existing studs (sister stud)and the put a drywall on it? Or any other ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can frame as you like to provide a surface for drywall. Use pressure-treated lumber when in contact with concrete. It's common practice to do so to surround steel posts, plumbing, etc.

If you have more specific questions, please update your post.

Comment: Citation is probably needed, for the pressure treated part of this answer. Some localities prohibit its use indoors, as well as requiring no more than a simple vapor barrier, at the point of contact. My basement, that was finished with untreated wood in the early 80's, and then subsequently ripped out, 20 years later, only had a painted floor; no signs of rot anywhere, except maybe for a few rusty nails. The permeability of the concrete is the problem, that leads to water related issues; pressure treated wood may be rot resistant to a point, but is by no means water resistant.

Comment: Since there's obviously PT lumber on the bottom plates now, it's a safe bet that this is appropriate in this case. Point taken in general.

Comment: As far as building the room I agree since it is not a load bearing wall.+